# VueJs Leaflet Get Color Function

Tags: leaflet, vue.js

I am using VueLeaflet to create a map like in this example: https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/examples/geo-json.html

I like to add some colors to the polygons like in this example:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

This is my try here: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-framework-mlc7b

```
 getcolorFunction(d) {
      return d > 1000
        ? "#800026"
        : d > 500
        ? "#BD0026"
        : d > 200
        ? "#E31A1C"
        : d > 100
        ? "#FC4E2A"
        : d > 50
        ? "#FD8D3C"
        : d > 20
        ? "#FEB24C"
        : d > 10
        ? "#FED976"
        : "#FFEDA0";
    },

    styleFunction() {
      const fillColor = this.fillColor; // important! need touch fillColor in computed for re-calculate when change fillColor
      return () => {
        return {
          weight: 2,
          color: "#ECEFF1",
          opacity: 1,
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.sales),
          fillOpacity: 1
        };
      };
    },

    onEachFeatureFunction() {
      if (!this.enableTooltip) {
        return () => {};
      }
      return (feature, layer) => {
        layer.bindTooltip(
          "<div>Name Province:" +
            feature.properties.varname_1 +
            "</div><div>Sales: " +
            feature.properties.sales +
            "</div>",
          { permanent: false, sticky: true }
        );
      };
    }
  },
```

How could I Get work that function getColor in Vue.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution way easier tha vue-choropleth if you are using reactive variables, just make sure you include a `v-if...` in `<LGeoJson...`

```
styleFunction() {
    return (feature) => {  //add feature here to access this prop
      return {
        weight: 2,
        color: "#d725bb",
        opacity: 1,
        fillColor: this.getColor(feature.properties.count),  //send it here
        fillOpacity: .65
      };
    };
  },
```

and

```
getColor() {
          return (d) => { //recieve the prop
            if(d>400){ //as many conditionals you need
              return "#7e0001"
            }
            if(d>100){
              return "#b82101"
            }
            if(d>50){
              return "#f44300"
            }
            if(d>10){
              return "#f96200"
            }
            if(d>5){
              return "#ff8200"
            }
            if(d>0){
              return "#fff154"
            }
            if(d==0){
              return "#0000000"
            }
```

Comment: I found this solution way easier tha vue-choropleth if you are using reactive variables,  just make sure you include a `v-if...` in `<LGeoJson...`